# Is it possible to overload a method this way?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to allow people to login using their UserID(int) or their username (string).  The way I thought about doing this is creating two seperate methods, one that accepts a string, and one that accepts an int.  But I could not get this to work and it seems there might be a better solution.

```
public static string ForgotPassword ( string username )
{
    using ( var conn = new SqlConnection( GetConnectionString() ) )
    using ( var cmd = conn.CreateCommand() )
    {
        conn.Open();
        cmd.CommandText =
        @"SELECT 
             Password 
         FROM 
             Distributor
         WHERE 
             Username = @username";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue( "@username", (string)username );
        using ( var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader() )
        {
            if ( !reader.Read() )
            {
                // no results found
                return null;
            }
            return reader.GetString( reader.GetOrdinal( "Password" ) );
        }
    }
}

public static string ForgotPassword ( int username )
{
    using ( var conn = new SqlConnection( GetConnectionString() ) )
    using ( var cmd = conn.CreateCommand() )
    {
        conn.Open();
        cmd.CommandText =
        @"SELECT 
             Password 
         FROM 
             Distributor
         WHERE 
             DistributorID= @username";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue( "@username", (int)username );
        using ( var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader() )
        {
            if ( !reader.Read() )
            {
                // no results found
                return null;
            }
            return reader.GetString( reader.GetOrdinal( "Password" ) );
        }
    }
}
```

What is the best way to allow them to login with a user_id or a username?

Comment: What didn't work when you tried it originally?

Comment: What error did you get with this approach?

Comment: I never received an error.  It always assumed I was calling the string version of the method.  I could login with testuser and 1234 as the password.  but when I did 101 and the password 1234 it would not find anything in the database.

Comment: Did you cast the argument as to int when you called ForgotPassword?

Comment: if the user enters 1234, you are probably treating it as a string value.  You will need to check if its numeric and convert it to an int for this to work.

Comment: @Tuan I thought I did, but I will have to double back and check.  It is possible I was not casting it correctly or even in the right place to begin with. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first method, I would get hold of the userId from that username, then pass that to the 2nd method.

If a username doesn't match a UserID, then return an error in the same way you would if the UserID doesn't exist.

```
public static string ForgotPassword ( string username )
{
    int userid = //Get userid from username
    return ForgotPassword(userid);
}

public static string ForgotPassword ( int username )
{
    using ( var conn = new SqlConnection( GetConnectionString() ) )
    using ( var cmd = conn.CreateCommand() )
    {
        conn.Open();
        cmd.CommandText =
        @"SELECT 
             Password 
         FROM 
             Distributor
         WHERE 
             DistributorID= @username";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue( "@username", (int)username );
        using ( var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader() )
        {
            if ( !reader.Read() )
            {
                // no results found
                return null;
            }
            return reader.GetString( reader.GetOrdinal( "Password" ) );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I will have to try this method, will get back to you.

Comment: and change parameter name for second method to `userId`  :)

Comment: @the_joric This shouldn't cause an issue. I kept it the same on purpose so its as close to the OP's original code. The main point is the use of calling the 2nd method from the 1st

Comment: I did not mean complilation issues -- just more solid naming. My comment is moslty for OP :)